# How to float center but still keep the propities of left float

Tags: html, css

So I want to float some div's center, orignally I was using `float: left` which gave me this look https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWao6.png after reading other answers I see that I can not do that, one of the suggestions made was to use `margin: 0 auto;` when I used this it made everything simply stack in a line down the center, as per this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rraoq.png

I am trying to force the floating div's to be stacked uniformly centered. Which would also adjust to the stack down the line in lower screensizes,

How best am I to do this?

So here is my CSS at the moment

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.item {
    float: left;

    max-width: 500px;


    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;


}
button {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: orange;
    border: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 02px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);

}
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="container orders">
<div class="item">
                <button class="ready">
                    /*content*/    

                </button>
            </div>
</div
```

Comment: add your code,what is size properties of your div

Comment: remove float:left and add display:inline-block; then you need to set the parent div text-align:center

Comment: If you want a good answer, supply a jsfiddle link with an example.

Comment: Thanks @naila works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `inline-block`

```
div {
    display: inline-block
}
```

By default divs are `block` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/m9d3jepz/

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .item {
      width: 45%;
      }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .item {
      width: 100%;
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is but If I were you I would try wrap those div's in another div with display: inline-block and clearfix. And then give parent text-align: center. End code should look something like that:

```css
.parent{
  text-align: center;
  }
.parent .container{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 340px;
  zoom: 1;
  }
.parent .container:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  }
.parent .container:before{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  }
.parent .container .element{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  bordeR: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want center a div so you have to remove float left you can add text-align center i parent div and add display inline-block in child div like this

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
.child{
  width:100px;
  background:#f00;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Some text here</div>
  <div class="child">Some text here</div>
  <div class="child">Some text here</div>
  <div class="child">Some text here</div>   
</div>
```